# I have an array that should be an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

There is an object in the data object, that I wrote as an object, but if I console.log it, the browser says that it's an array. But I clearly gave it the object brackets. The tutorial that I am watching also works with this like an array. The code works fine, but I can't sleep without the answer.

```
var budgetController = (function() {

    var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
       this.id = id;
       this.description = description;
       this.value = value;      


    };

    var Income = function(id, description, value) {
       this.id = id;
       this.description = description;
       this.value = value;      


    };

    var data = {
        allItems: {   //Here is the object
            exp: [],
            inc: [],
        },
        totals: {
            exp: 0,
            inc: 0,
        },
    };
    return {
        addItem: function(type, des, val){
            var newItem, ID;
            //ID = last ID + 1
            ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
            if (type === 'exp') {
                newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
            } else if (type === 'inc') {
                newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
            }
            console.log(data.allItems[type]);
            data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
            return newItem;
        },
    };
 })();

 budgetController.addItem('inc', 'test', 22);
```

[image: Here is the console.log with the array]
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: console.log(data.allItems); instead of console.log(data.allItems[type]);

Comment: +1 for what @RomanKushin said. You are console.log-ing the arrays that are children of allItems, you are not console.log-ing the object allItems.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it out, and that was the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're 1 level deeper in the object than you think. The code in question printing your array is `console.log(data.allItems[type])`. Per your function call, `type === 'inc'`.

```
data === {
    allItems: {   
        exp: [],
        inc: [],
    },
    totals: {
        exp: 0,
        inc: 0,
    },
};

data.allItems === {   
    exp: [],
    inc: [],
},
```

And finally, the piece of the puzzle you're actually printing:

```
data.allItems['inc'] === data.allItems.inc === []
```